# Context merge in nested velocity templates

Tags: java, velocity

I have following velocity template with name `exception.vm`:

```
<span class="classname">$s.getClassName().</span>
```

I include this in another template with name `cause.vm`:

```
#include("templates/exception.vm")
<span class="classname">$s.getCause()</span>
```

When I merge this with a context:

```
Template tm = VelocityUtil.getTemplate("templates/cause.htm");
Context c = new VelocityContext();
c.put("s", new RuntimeException());
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(100);
tm.merge(c, sw);
```

The `$s.getCause()` gets interpreted properly but `$s.getClassName()` does not get interpreted and prints as a literal.

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
#parse("templates/exception.htm")
```

Instead of:

```
#include("templates/exception.vm")
```

`#include` includes the resource without interpreting it.